# Slcomposeviewcontroller automatic close after few second iOS 8

Tags: ios

i use this code ( works perfectly in IOS 7 )

```
mySLComposerSheet = [[SLComposeViewController alloc] init];
mySLComposerSheet = [SLComposeViewController    composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
[mySLComposerSheet setInitialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",annotazioni.text]];
[mySLComposerSheet addImage:ScreenshotForShare];
[self presentViewController:mySLComposerSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
if (!mySLComposerSheet) {
    return;
}else{

}
[mySLComposerSheet setCompletionHandler:^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result) {

    switch (result) {
        case SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
            NSLog(@"Post Canceled");
            break;
        case SLComposeViewControllerResultDone:
            NSLog(@"Post Sucessful");
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}];
```

BUT, when slcomposerview appear, after 1-2 seconds disappear without any input command, in simulator and device ...
What is the correct code?

My other way for posting photo is this :

```
NSString *client_id = @"123456789012345"; (The same of .Plist)
fbGraph = [[FbGraph alloc] initWithFbClientID:client_id];
[fbGraph authenticateUserWithCallbackObject:self andSelector:@selector(postInAppFacebook) andExtendedPermissions:@"user_photos,user_videos,publish_stream,offline_access" andSuperView:self.view];

NSMutableDictionary *variables = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:3];
FbGraphFile *graph_file = [[FbGraphFile alloc] initWithImage:ScreenshotForShare];
[variables setObject:graph_file forKey:@"file"];
[variables setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",annotazioni.text] forKey:@"message"];
[fbGraph doGraphPost:@"me/photos" withPostVars:variables];
if (TwitterShare == YES) {
    [self ShareOnTwitter];
}else{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

BUT ONLY IN IOS 8 i receive error 191... On IOS 7 all works perfectly and the photo was posted on my diary correctly.
Help me plase i can't find a solution after 7 day's ...
Thank's in advance

Comment: Your code works fine for me. How are you declaring mySLComposerSheet?

Comment: In IOS 8? I declare mySLComposerSheet in .h with framework, why? You have declare in other position and Works? :)

Comment: I wanted to make sure you declared it as strong (which is what I did). You should post the actual error message that you're getting.

Comment: I don't recive any error because my composer when automatically close show my below view and nothing happen this is my problem :(

Comment: What does "IN IOS 8 i receive error 191" mean then?

Comment: Ah sorry, i receive error 191 invalid redirect_uri but of i test my app on iPhone 4 with iOS 7 all works and my image was sent to my diary correctly

Comment: With my second code not with sl composer attention :)